# File permissions for php

Tags: php, linux, server

I have a problem. I have a PHP website on a server. Yesterday I have created a new PHP file that should open and write txt file.

Code:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

When I tried it it was not able to open the file. I have already checked for spelling mistakes and I did not find any. I think the problem is in file permissions.

Here are my permissions to files in the directory of PHP file:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oliver oliver 738 Jun 21 11:56 Dotaznik.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oliver oliver 182 Jun 21 12:09 fwrite.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oliver oliver   0 Jun 21 12:50 newfile.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oliver oliver   0 Sep 18  2019 odpovede.txt
```

I am new to Linux.
This is the link to it:
https://kruzok.net/oliver/Moje_stranky/Dotaznik/
Thanks

Comment: "not able to open the file" Manually as user Oliver or by a php script?

Comment: owner should be the webserver. Default is www-data:www-data.

Comment: Try `get_current_user()` to see who owns the script you're running to write the file. If it's not you, you probably have to `chmod()` the file

Comment: @Michel it is by php script

Comment: @Michel should I write it into console or PHP file?

Comment: That file belongs to `oliver` and others cannot write to it. Your web server doesn't run as `oliver`, does it? This doesn't really have much to do with PHP, it's how file permissions work in most operating systems (users, groups and permissions).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you are right. It is school server. The problem is that  I do not know how to change those permissions. I already tried some things I found on internet but it did not work. How should I change those permissions?

Comment: [Unix / Linux - File Permission / Access Modes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm)